# Maximum number of Imageviews tolerable in Activity?

Tags: java, android, performance, imageview

In another OS post someone mentioned adding Imageviews to an array. Has anyone done a performance measurement on, say "max number of Imageviews", being displayed and animated?

This question is really about figuring out whether or not I will need to remove Imageviews periodically along the way as more and more get added and animated.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, removing the older images above some limit (100, 200?) should be a good idea to keep the app "afloat". Anyway, no real user is able to watch more than say 100 full-screen images on a device in one sit :)

Comment: Yes. What I noticed is that old and unused imageviews must be removed. They significantly impact performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be device dependent.  Older devices have less application memory available than new devices, etc.

The maximum number of `ImageView`s will also depend heavily on what the image size is.  For example, if you have one `ImageView` that has an image that is 10000 x 10000, that single image view probably won't load.  The number of 32 x 32 `ImageView`s is going to be very large.  If you mean an ImageView without any content, then that number will probably be on the order of 1000's or more.

However, since you mentioned being displayed (and animated), then they would depend on the number of pixels in their bitmaps.  Animations should really affect the "max number".